# Ecommerce Subscription for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, e-commerce, google-checkout

Have seen some conversations revolving around this, but hoping for some current input as to perhaps the best libs and services available for Rails developers at the moment who are implementing a subscription membership based website.

I'm interested in any libs or frameworks with which you may be familiar through GitHub or elsewhere as well as what service has given you the best experience so far for clients and your own sanity?  I'm leaning towards paypal and perhaps also including Google Checkout, however there are certainly a lot of other options.

I'd like for it to be clean and to appear as integrated into the website as possible while carrying the trust of a larger service provider such as PayPal and Google.

Additionally, these are mostly micro payments at around $1.00 USD.  Sometimes purchases go up to $15 to $30.

- EDIT:  Since initial post I've found SaaS Rails Kit (http://railskits.com/recurring_billing/).  Has anyone had experience with this vs Recurly?  Doing some research as per the first answer, it appears Recurly is the superior option at this point for our model, however this Rails Kit may be an even better option if it has met some very positive experiences in comparison with other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one I prefer: [Chargify](http://chargify.com/) (soon to be available on heroku)

Another I know but haven't used: [Recurly](http://recurly.com/) (soon on heroku too)

Comment: Very interesting.  I'd sure like to see a solid lineup between the two.  And the Heroku availability (well, after I beg and plead to get into the beta) is very attractive as that is what I'm deploying to.

Comment: I did additionally find this nice post by Chris Crompton on Recurly vs Chargify: http://bit.ly/rnKjjE  He further links to a spreadsheet that has a feature by feature comparison that seems rather comprehensive: http://bit.ly/p9P6GB

Comment: Hey, just an FYI, I'm seriously considering using SaaS Kit from RailsKits.com.  I realize that it's missing some of the functionality of other systems, obviously, however it also obviates the ~25¢+ per transaction tax of using a system like these others.  It further, if you use the right gateway, allows you to "own" your buyer's data insomuch that you can switch if the time comes where you need to. Something I'm considering right now and weighing carefully.

Comment: @ylluminate: What did you end up choosing? If you went with SaaS Kit, what was your experience with it?

Comment: Ended up using Stripe & PayPal and essentially rolling our own solution.  I THINK that activemerchant will work now, but we just felt like we needed more control with the uncertainty rolling around at the time.  But yes, Stripe is a real winner and our default payment mechanism now.